# AppHangB1 causing vs 2010 in not responding mode while editing webforms

Tags: visual-studio-2010

i was trying to change the table's width in IDE and then saving and refreshing my localhost version of the application. it was working fine but suddenly i found that whenever i made any changes to my design the IDE gets hang and it says not responding and it takes quite much time to resume. after several time of this happening and restarting IDE and computer, i still got the same problem and when i closed the not responding IDE by force then in view error detail i found that APPHangB1 is causing problem, it says something like this "program is unable to communicate with windows due to AppHangB1 ". what is teh problem kindly tell? shall i reinstall my VS 2010. i have stuck in the middle and have to complete my application fast. kindly suggest solutions if u faced any. i m in hurry